# detect new factor level appeared cumulatively by time and group

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose a retailer wants to detect whether a customer buys a new product category for each visit and the cumulative unique categories purchased up to each visit. In this example, Tom buys paper at time 1 and time 2, but paper at time 2 does not count as the new product category because he purchased paper already at time 1. The total cumulative unique product is at variable "time" level. Say if time means week, we are interested in the total unique product up to this week.

Data

```
user<-c("Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom","Jim","Jim")
t<-c("1", "1", "1","2","2","1","2")
product<-c("cpu","paper","ssd","watch","paper","water","water")
dt<-data.frame(user,t,product)
  user t product
1  Tom 1     cpu
2  Tom 1   paper
3  Tom 1     ssd
4  Tom 2   watch
5  Tom 2   paper
6  Jim 1   water
7  Jim 2   water
```

Desired output

```
  user t product new_product_dummy total_cumulative_unique_product
1  Tom 1     cpu                 y                               3
2  Tom 1   paper                 y                               3
3  Tom 1     ssd                 y                               3
4  Tom 2   watch                 y                               4
5  Tom 2   paper                 n                               4
6  Jim 1   water                 y                               1
7  Jim 2   water                 n                               1
```

My logic is to compare the product purchased with the cumulative unique factor levels up to date but I could not figure how to code it.

date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why the `total_cumulative_unique_product` for the first three rows is equal to `3`, as this does not seem to be a *cumulative* number. So I assume this is a mistake (if this is in fact correct, please skip to option 2).

### Option 1

You can do the following using a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse);
library(tidyverse);
dt %>%
    group_by(user, product) %>%
    mutate(
        n = 1:n(),
        new_product_dummy = ifelse(n == 1, "y", "n")) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    mutate(
        total_cumulative_unique_product = cumsum(new_product_dummy == "y"))
## A tibble: 7 x 5
## Groups:   user [2]
#  user  t     product new_product_dummy total_cumulative_unique_product
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <chr>                                       <int>
#1 Tom   1     cpu     y                                               1
#2 Tom   1     paper   y                                               2
#3 Tom   1     ssd     y                                               3
#4 Tom   2     watch   y                                               4
#5 Tom   2     paper   n                                               4
#6 Jim   1     water   y                                               1
#7 Jim   2     water   n                                               1
```

---

### Option 2

To *exactly* reproduce your expected output you can do

```
dt %>%
    group_by(user, product) %>%
    mutate(
        n = 1:n(),
        new_product_dummy = ifelse(n == 1, "y", "n")) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    mutate(
        total_cumulative_unique_product = cumsum(new_product_dummy == "y")) %>%
    group_by(user, t) %>%
    mutate(
        total_cumulative_unique_product = max(total_cumulative_unique_product))
## A tibble: 7 x 5
## Groups:   user, t [4]
#  user  t     product new_product_dummy total_cumulative_unique_product
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <chr>                                       <dbl>
#1 Tom   1     cpu     y                                              3.
#2 Tom   1     paper   y                                              3.
#3 Tom   1     ssd     y                                              3.
#4 Tom   2     watch   y                                              4.
#5 Tom   2     paper   n                                              4.
#6 Jim   1     water   y                                              1.
#7 Jim   2     water   n                                              1.
```

---

### Update

To ensure `t`-ordering on the `user` group level:

```
dt %>%
    arrange(user, t) %>%
    group_by(user, product) %>%
    mutate(
        n = 1:n(),
        new_product_dummy = ifelse(n == 1, "y", "n")) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    mutate(
        total_cumulative_unique_product = cumsum(new_product_dummy == "y")) %>%
    group_by(user, t) %>%
    mutate(
        total_cumulative_unique_product = max(total_cumulative_unique_product))
## A tibble: 7 x 5
## Groups:   user, t [4]
#  user  t     product new_product_dummy total_cumulative_unique_product
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <chr>                                       <dbl>
#1 Jim   1     water   y                                              1.
#2 Jim   2     water   n                                              1.
#3 Tom   1     cpu     y                                              3.
#4 Tom   1     paper   y                                              3.
#5 Tom   1     ssd     y                                              3.
#6 Tom   2     watch   y                                              4.
#7 Tom   2     paper   n                                              4.
```

Comment: The reason the cumulative is 3 is because I count it on the level of the time variable. Tom purchases all three of them at Time 1, I treat it as three instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: @alphabetagamma Yes I understood that; but *cumulative* suggests it increases (*accumulates*) within `t`. Either way, option 2 should be what you're after, isn't it? You can see that `total_cumulative_unique_product` is the *maximum* of the cumulative sum where `new_product_dummy == "y"` at the `t` group level.

Comment: In creating the new_product_dummy, you did not rank by t, which is brilliant. I assume, the first appeared product will always be label by "y" regardless of the time ranking right? Do I have to rank my data by time first?

Comment: @alphabetagamma In the first step I group rows by `user` and `product`; I then consecutively number identical products, and the first occurrence of a product gets flagged with `"y"`. Your sample data is `t`-ordered on the `user` level; if that's not the case in your bigger data set you need to ensure proper ordering (see my edit).

Comment: @alphabetagamma *"I assume, the first appeared product will always be label by "y" regardless of the time ranking right"* In short, yes;-)